# undefined index in case of radio button in php

Tags: php

I am new in PHP. I am making an online exam system. I use radio button to take the answer. they are used in such a way so that each question ends up with a set of radio button. So I use while loop to retrieve the question from database and to put the radios. Now when I going to check the value of radio it shows "Notice: Undefined index: ques1 " .

```
<html>
<head>
<title>EXAM</title>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
 $i=1;
 $j=1;
 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "online_exam";
 $server = "127.0.0.1";
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database);
 if ($db_found)
 { session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['b_subject']))
    {
       $selected_button=$_POST['subject'];
       if($selected_button=='subject1')
            $_SESSION['$sub']= "GK";
        else if($selected_button=='subject2')
            $_SESSION['$sub']="math";
        else
            print "error";
    }

      $c = $_SESSION['$cour'];
  $s = $_SESSION['$sub'];
  $SQL = "SELECT ques FROM ques_ans WHERE course='$c' AND subj='$s'";
  $result = mysql_query($SQL);
  while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
    {
         print $db_field['ques']."<BR>";
?>
<FORM name ="form1" method ="post"  >  
         <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques'.$i value= '1'>YES
         <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques'.$i value= '0'>NO
</FORM>        
<?PHP           
          $i++;         
    }     
  mysql_close($db_handle);
}
?>
<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" > 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</FORM>
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$selected_radio = $_POST['ques'.$j];
 if ($selected_radio == '1') 
  {
   $ans='1';
  }
 else if ($selected_radio == '0') 
  {
    $ans='0';
  }
print $ans;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're learning MySQL, look into PDO now rather than later since it'll teach you safe MySQL. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Fixed the echo out and you were echoing a seperate form out, all inputs need to be in the same <form>


<html>
<head>
<title>EXAM</title>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
 $i=1;
 $j=1;
 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "online_exam";
 $server = "127.0.0.1";
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database);
 if ($db_found)
 { session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['b_subject']))
    {
       $selected_button=$_POST['subject'];
       if($selected_button=='subject1')
            $_SESSION['$sub']= "GK";
        else if($selected_button=='subject2')
            $_SESSION['$sub']="math";
        else
            print "error";
    }

      $c = $_SESSION['$cour'];
  $s = $_SESSION['$sub'];
  $SQL = "SELECT ques FROM ques_ans WHERE course='$c' AND subj='$s'";
  $result = mysql_query($SQL);
echo '<FORM name ="form1" method ="post"  >'; // Echo the form header
  while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
    {
         print $db_field['ques']."<BR>";
?>
             <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques<?PHP echo $i;?>' value= '1'>YES
             <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques<?PHP echo $i;?>' value= '0'>NO       
<?PHP           
          $i++;         
    }     
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"></form>'; // Close form
  mysql_close($db_handle);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$selected_radio = $_POST['ques'.$j];
 if ($selected_radio == '1') 
  {
   $ans='1';
  }
 else if ($selected_radio == '0') 
  {
    $ans='0';
  }
print $ans;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To anyone wondering why I didn't use <?=$i?> - It's because I know not every configuration supports short-tags:) Just felt I should let that be known.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have changed that portion. But when I write "$selected_radio = $_POST['ques1'];" to check. but "Undefined index: ques1 " is showing....

Comment: The issue is you are sending TWO forms, so the form the button is on, doesn't get the question data. the code should work now. Will setup my own copy and verify.

Comment: Confirmed it works, in regards to the form. You will need to write the rest of the logic.

Comment: thanks Thomas... It really works... you help me to learn a new thing . . thanks :)